# Android Drawable Shapes Animation

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, drawable

How to draw this shape using android drawable whether by using XML or java with animation of the dark lines from right to left?

[image]

Comment: Do you want steady lines or lines with shimmer animation ?

Comment: shimmer animation @Dipalis.

Comment: If your requirement is for `API level >21 use AnimatedVectorDrawable`.